# Call method with parameter from jQuery or Ajax

Tags: java, javascript, function, parameters

Do you have some sample code that from you can show how to call java method from your Ajax? The following code can call the Java method:

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST",
url: "test.java",
data: data,
success : function (data) 
{ // Your return categories in data // Append list options to select2 }
});
```

But here in the URL how should I need to pass the URL and how I pass the method parameter?

Comment: You set up a service that can handle the call; you don't call it directly. That said, things like DWR can make it *look* like you're calling it directly.

Comment: You need a Java Servlet engine (e.g. Jetty) running on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax uses the http protocol to communicate with a server. Therefore, you simply write a servlet or jsp to process the Ajax request. The inputs are passed in using query arguments and your servlet/jsp returns its output as text.

The output can be in whatever format you decide. Typical formats are plain text, xml, or json. Personally, I prefer to pass back a javascript object literal which can be parsed by the eval function. This allows me to pass back very complex data which might include strings, numbers, Booleans, arrays, and objects. But the code to parse the output is a simple eval call.

Below is some example code. The ajax calls a jsp which takes 2 numbers as inputs and returns their sum, difference, product and quotient. Here is the jsp code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/plain"%>
<%

// get the input values
double val1 = 0;
double val2 = 0;
String errorMsg = "";
try {
    val1 = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("val1"));
    val2 = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("val2"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    errorMsg = "Non-numeric input";
}

// return the javascript object literal
String result = "({";
result += " val1 : " + val1 + ",";
result += " val2 : " + val2 + ",";
result += " sum : " + (val1 + val2) + ",";
result += " difference : " + (val1 - val2) + ",";
result += " product : " + (val1 * val2) + ",";
result += " quotient : " + (val1 / val2) + ",";
result += " errorMsg : \"" + errorMsg + "\"";
result += "})";
out.println(result);
%>
```

Here is a javascript function that makes an ajax call to the jsp above and processes the output.

```
function calculate(value1, value2) {
    var dataObj = {val1 : value1, val2 : value2};
    $.ajax({
        url : 'calculator.jsp',
        dataType : 'text',
        data : dataObj,
        cache : false, // guarantees jsp is always called
        success: function(data) {
            var result = eval(data);
            var msg;
            if (result.errorMsg != '') {
                msg = result.errorMsg;
            } else {
                msg = result.val1 + " + " + result.val2 + " = " + result.sum + '\n';
                msg += result.val1 + " - " + result.val2 + " = " + result.difference + '\n';
                msg += result.val1 + " * " + result.val2 + " = " + result.product + '\n';
                msg += result.val1 + " / " + result.val2 + " = " + result.quotient;
            }
            alert(msg);
        }
   });
}
```